# How to use methods of Cordova Facebook Plugin?

Tags: android, facebook, cordova, ionic-framework

I am using Facebook plugin (http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/facebook/
) of Cordova.  I am using this plugin with ionic framework. I am all done with installing this plugin on android. I have created an appId and the app is under development. So for the testing I am using test user generated in - https://developers.facebook.com/apps/123456789/roles/test-users/ I want to share a feed on Facebook but I am not able to do that. I am checking getLoginStatus method and on its success I want to post a feed. Here is my code

```
      $scope.getFbLoginStatus = function(){
      $cordovaFacebook.getLoginStatus()
       .then(function(success) {  
         alert("Logged In");
         $scope.shareFeed = function(){
         $cordovaFacebook.showDialog({method: "feed", link:"https://github.com/Wizcorp/phonegap-facebook-plugin/commit/7b4a56f5717a50d3387abe4a2fa6156fe1aea852", caption: "Here is the caption"
})
      .then(function(success) {
         alert("check whether image shared or not" );
         // success
       }, function (error) {
        alert("image not shared");
        // error
        });
       }
       }, function (error) {
       alert("Permission denied");
      });
     }
```

I have not used facebook SDK  as it was not listed in the installation steps. 
I want to implement Facebook feed dialog using ionic framework. Please help me and suggest where I am going wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was problem in the Facebook app-id. It is working fine now. Make sure you generate the correct key hash for the settings of Facebook app_id.